# TextView returning nil

Tags: swift, null, textview

I have a textview on a nib and hooked the nib to a swift file.

I have set the ibOutlet for the textview and and trying to change the text, but it is returning nil. I have it set to selectable and editable any ideas?

```
@IBOutlet weak var page22TextView: UITextView? 
var strTitle: String!
var pageIndex: Int = 0
var bookPageNumber = ""
var indexPageSum: Int!
var isHidden:Bool = false
var textBoxP22 = ""

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation : UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return isHidden
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    page22TextView?.delegate = self

    self.page22TextView?.text = "work"

    if page22TextView == nil {
        print("I am Nil")   
    } else {
        page22TextView?.text = "name"
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you're checking that the _entire_ text view is nil, not its text value. With that in mind, you have a bigger problem, in that your text view probably isn't connected to the nib property and likely isn't being instantiated.

Comment: if the **page22TextView** is connected properly and returns nil in viewDidLoad, this could mean your viewController has not loaded all it's views yet. Try moving your code in viewDidAppear and see what happens

Comment: How are you instantiating this `ViewController`? Also, to above comment, the outlets should be connected before a call to viewDidLoad so is not a problem.

Comment: Try deleting the outlet and drag it again. The optional type of the TextView concerns me. The automatically generated code uses TextView! not optional. Which version of Xcode and Swift are you using?

Comment: Thanks all, Moving it to view did appear  worked but I also reset the link. I also changed the the textview back to !. I changed it Because I was getting nil and forgot to change back.